# The machine readable part of my passport no longer includes my middle name. Is that a problem?

Tags: air-travel, passport-renewals

The machine readable part of my passport used to give my last name and my *middle* name only. Now it gives my last name and my *first* name only. (This is due to change in regulations when I got a new passport. Both names appear in my passport. However, I have never used my first name.)

> #### Before
>
> *Name:* Edgar Allan Poe
> `P<USAPOE<<ALLAN<<<<<<<<<<<`
>
> #### Now
>
> *Name:* Edgar Allan Poe
> `P<USAPOE<<EDGAR<<<<<<<<<<<`

Can I book my ticket only with my middle name (as Allan Poe) to make an international flight?

I usually book via my frequent flyer profile, which I set up for `Allan Poe`. (The name can't easily be changed in the profile and I prefer to travel on my middle name.)

Comment: Why do you think the machine readable part even matters?

Comment: It is probably what allowed me to check in with my middle name without any problems. The scanned name agrees with the name on the ticket. Now this would be no longer the case. My question is whether this matters or not.

Comment: Where do you plan on scanning your passport? You can usually check-in online without scanning anything.

Comment: When I drop off my baggage the airline usually scans my passport. Will they complain that my name isn't what it says on my passport? Or do they only require that some given name on my passport match the first name on the ticket?

Comment: But your passport still has the other name printed on, right?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: So, you name is Edgar Allan Poe.  Your old Passport said only Allan Poe but you new Passport says Edgar Poe or Edgar Allan Poe?.  All you travel Profiles are still Allan Poe.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the gate agents usually scan your passport to get your details quickly, they can also take a look at the document itself if there's an inconsistency. Therefore you don't need to worry - just fly as usual.